# R multi boxplot in one graph with value (quantile)

Tags: r, data-visualization, boxplot, quantile

How to create multiple  boxplot with value shown in R ?

Now I'm using this code

```
boxplot(Data_frame[  ,2] ~ Data_frame[  ,3], )
```

I tried to use this

```
boxplot(Data_frame[  ,2] ~   Data_frame[  ,3],     ) 
text(y=fivenum(Data_frame$x), labels =fivenum(Data_frame$x), x=1.25)
```

But only first boxplot have value. How to show value in all boxplot in one graph.

Thank you so much!

Comment: Can you provide a sample of your data.frame?

Comment: x <- data.frame( 
c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3),
c(5,10,15,20,30,50,70,80,100,5,7,9,11,15,17,19,17,19,100,200,300,400,500,700,1000,200))

names(x) <- c("Time", "Value")



=> So now I would like to plot the value over the Time. We will have a graph with 3 boxplot (Time 1,2,3), in each boxplot, it must show value of Median, P10, P90..)

Comment: This does not fit to the code you provide. When you ask question it is really helpful to provide fully reproducible example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understand your question (it is not clear how the `fivenum` summary should be displayed) here is one solution. It presents the summary using the top axis.

```
x <- data.frame( 
    Time = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3), 
    Value = c(5,10,15,20,30,50,70,80,100,5,7,9,11,15,17,19,17,19,100,200,300,400,500,700,1000,200))

boxplot(x$Value ~ x$Time) 
fivenums <- aggregate(x$Value, by=list(Time=x$Time), FUN=fivenum)
labels <- apply(fivenums[,-1], 1, function(x) paste(x[-1], collapse = ", "))
axis(3, at=fivenums[,1],labels=labels, las=1, col.axis="red")
```

[image]

Of course you can additionally play with the font size or rotation for this summary. Moreover you can break the line in one place, so the label will have smaller width.

**Edit**
In order to get what have you posted in the comment below you can add

```
text(x = 3 + 0.5, y = fivenums[3,-1], labels=fivenums[3,-1])
```

and you will get

[image]

however it won't be readable for other boxplots.

Comment: I think your code is fine. I will try it now. thank you. pls vote for my question if you think it can help other people.

Comment: In order for you question to be helpful you should really do a bit of cleanup there. Please put the example data set from the comment in the question. Change variable names in the code you provided so they are compatible with the data structure (the code will be reproducible) Then it will make a helpful question

Comment: I dont know why I still cannot do that.

Comment: a <- data.frame(
    Rank = c(1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,3,2,1,3,2,1,2,1,3,3,3,1,1,2,2,1,3 ),
    Time = c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3), 
    Value = c(5,10,15,20,30,50,70,80,100,5,7,9,11,15,17,19,17,19,100,200,300,400,500,700,1000,200))

boxplot(a$Value[a$Rank==1] ~ a$Time[a$Rank==1]) 
fivenums <- aggregate(a$Value[a$Rank==1], by=list(Time=a$Time[a$Rank==1]), FUN=fivenum)
labels <- apply(fivenums, 1, function(a) paste(a, collapse = ", "))
axis(3, at=fivenums[,1],labels=labels, las=1, col.axis="red")    => it does not work :) how to solve TIME =0

Comment: 1. you should set at values in a different way, here: 
`axis(3, at=1:length(unique(a$Time)), labels=labels, las=1, col.axis="red")`
2. The image you have posted should have been in the question from the very begining... I have updated the answer

Comment: But I only shown one time ( in your picture), the reason is both two first box plot is so small ?

Comment: The reason is simple I całl the `text` function for the third box.

Comment: could you please help me call text func for all box?

Comment: You have to pass proper parameters (where I put PARAM) to the `text` function:
`text(x = PARAM + 0.5, y = fivenums[PARAM,-1], labels=fivenums[PARAM,-1])`